# how to convert kateshcema files to new kate color theme files

Tags: python, appearance, kate, syntax-highlighting, pipenv

I found this [page](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kate/katepart/color-themes.html) that says to use kateschema_to_theme_converter.py [from](https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/syntax-highlighting)

no matter what I tried I couldnt get it to work. I am new to python.

I tried following the instructions in this [readme](https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/syntax-highlighting/-/blob/master/utils/schema-converter/README.rst) but installing pipenv and then running `pipenv install --dev` inside the folder where the readme is, gave a lot of errors and i had to restart.

I really want to convert [blue-mood theme](https://github.com/blue-mood/blue-mood-kate) to be usable; any help is appreciated.